# Improve the performance of array operations

Tags: python, arrays, performance, optimization

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/ZUBSPOIL) problem statement on [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/). 
The problem statement in a nutshell is:
Find out the value(explanation coming up) of array with 'n' elements after updating the array each time, 'q' times.

value of the array means, sum of the absolute differences of consecutive elements of the array.
e.g.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

value(array) = abs(1-2) + abs(2-3) + ... + abs(4-5)
```

I am learning python (3rd day into it) and am trying to solve the problem using the following python code.

```
def update(arr,find,replace):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i]==find:
            arr[i]=replace

def value(arr):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        sum = sum + abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1])
    return sum

test_case = int(input())
while test_case > 0 :
    n,q = map(int,input().split(" "))
    array = list(map(int,input().split()))
    for i in range(q):
        x,y = map(int,input().split(" "))
        update(array,x,y)
        print(value(array))
    test_case -= 1
```

This code, when I run on my machine is yielding correct results for custom test cases (even with large input) but on the site exceeds the time limit. Is there any way we can optimise the code to fit it into the given constraints...... time complexity : < 2secs and size : 50000bytes?

Comment: Use the [sum function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) vs clobbering it by using its name for a less efficient summation

Comment: Ummm...But then how would I sum the difference of absolute values? You see, I am not supposed to return just the sum of the array. The sum's twisted

Comment: With a comprehension

Comment: I think `return sum(abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]) for i in range(len(arr)-1))` works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two *potential* speedups (NOT tested):

```
def value(arr):
    return sum(abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]) for i in range(len(arr)-1))

# in general, avoid using built-in names for variable names also...
```

And:

```
def update(arr,find,replace):
    for i in range(arr.count(find)):
       arr[arr.index(find)]=replace

# find the specific replacements and replace vs 
# iterating the entire list
```

In Python:

1. Built-in functions are *usually* faster than what you would write yourself;
2. Comprehensions are *usually* faster than a traditional `for` loop;
3. Finding the specific replacement is faster than looping over an entire list.